# Error retrieving users: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUsers')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, electron, desktop

dbmng.js for connection to database:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('ticketDb.db');

async function getUsers(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('getUsers function is called');
    const qry = "SELECT * FROM User";
    db.all(qry, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error retrieving users:', err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Users data:', users); 
        resolve(res);
        
      }
    });
  });
};

console.log(getUsers())

module.exports = {
  getUsers: getUsers
};
```

main.js (I don't know if it is good to `putipcmain` here, I am trying to figure out `ipcMain` and `contextBridge`):

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const dbmgr = require('../src/models/dbmgr');

const path = require('path')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width:1200,
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, '../src/preload.js'),
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
        }
    })

    win.loadURL(
        isDev
        ? 'http://localhost:3000'
        : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
        )

        ipcMain.on('getUsers', async (event) => {
            try {
              const users = await dbmgr.getUsers();
              event.reply('usersData', users);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error retrieving users:', error);
              event.reply('usersData', []);
            }
          });
          
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

user-list.jsx (I have `UserList-example` rendering page):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


const UserList = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await window.api.getUsers();
        setUsers(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving users:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="users">
      {users.map((user) => (
        <div key={user.Id}>
          <span>{user.Email}</span>
          <span>{user.Password}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

I am using Electron as backend and for frontend React, the database is SQLite. The error:

> Error retrieving users: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUsers'),

It could be anything. I could not find out.

preload.js:

```
    const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
  getUsers: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      ipcRenderer.once('usersData', (_, data) => {
        resolve(data);
      });

      ipcRenderer.send('getUsers');
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: Where is `window.api.getUsers()` coming from? I don't see you adding it anywhere

Comment: window.api.getUsers(), it comes from preload.js I just edited the question

Comment: At first glance there isn't anything that strikes as being off. Looking into the issue i found a [github bug report with a similar issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35204) where someone solved it by changing the `BrowserWindow` params. Have you seen this?

Comment: adding full path to database solved my problem :)